# How to work with env variables in Bitbucket and different branches

Tags: bitbucket

Good morning,

i cant find some useful doc to get started with env variables in Bitbucket.

My Starting Point: .env file with `APP_ENV=$APP_ENV`. I commit to dev-master branch where is set a repo variable APP_ENV | dev. Ok, something is going wrong after commit, because this var isnt replaced. Is'nt it the default behaviour to replace this var after commit?

The second Question is: i want to set APP_ENV | prod after merge to production build but since the first case isnt work, the prod doesnt work too and where i can set the branch specific vars?

Thanks for your ideas and time.

.env file

```
APP_ENV=$APP_ENV
```

pipelines.yml

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    dev-master:
      - step:
          script:
          - 'sed -i "s/APP_ENV/$APP_ENV/" .env'
```

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

Comment: @Randommm yeah i know this doc and thatswhy i added ` 'sed -i "s/APP_ENV/$APP_ENV/" .env'` to the pipelines. The script is running after commit but the value is not changed.

Comment: You mean in the repo? You can't edit the files in the pipeline like that

Comment: ok, do u have an idea to switch from .env dev to prod without manually change the files? There must be an auto script... i have no idea at the moment